# Pure Javascript Post Browser Width Before Page Load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to post user's browser width **before image tags load**.

I'm using this code but its working after page load.

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", 'ajax/window.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send('width='+width+'&height='+height);
```

Is that possible? I need to create a session which is keeps the user's browser width BEFORE IMAGE TAGS LOAD.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? This looks like an XY problem; sending the window dimensions to server side seems odd. Especially with the requirement to do it before image tags load; do you want to dynamically modify the dimensions of images based on the window size from the server?

Comment: yes, im trying to resize images based on window size. do you know a better way?

Comment: no its not like that. im creating session on server side (holds user's browser width). then im creating this using that session:  <img src="images/500x200/blabla.jpg"> its not a static img url actually. im redirecting this to a php file (with htaccess) and that php file resizes image and shows. so you write whatever instead of 500x200 it will work

Comment: @101arrowz, why would it matter if they join a site at the same time? It shouldn't. But, recreating an image dynamically with PHP, will most likely be slower than an original load of an image slightly too large that is vector scaled by the Client's Browser.

Comment: Are you sure you need to resize the images though? Why not just have the master `blabla.jpg` and resize on client side? There are many ways to crop and cut to your heart's content with [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp).

Comment: @StackSlave im gonna use cache for that its not a problem, guys just tell me how can i post width before page load, dont think rest of that :)

Comment: The window has to load.

Comment: Yes. The sad truth is that JavaScript cannot run until it is fully parsed, which usually happens asynchronously as the HTML renders (and therefore the image tags are loaded).

Comment: @Cihan Please consider using CSS to dynamically resize images on the client side.

Comment: you get me wrong @101arrowz css doesnt solve my problem. im trying to load images without excess size. but not a few specific size. there is too much size in my situation. sorry for my english

Comment: If you insist there's no other way, try Jacob's solution. I would note that dynamic image resizing can lead to (excruciatingly) slow performance, and for that reason most sites use CSS with image resizing and highly compressed images.

Comment: @Cihan maybe if you elaborate on your business case, we can help a bit more, because what you're asking is going to be rough performance-wise.

Comment: If anything, you should try solving this by setting a cookie on the client side, not by trying to make a time-consuming HTTP request at this point. If your script is executed in a “blocking” manner, then there’s a good chance this cookie will already be send with the image requests, when those start to happen.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

It's not up to me to decide if this is a good practice. You're making your application how you see fit. A few things to think over.

1. What happens if the user resizes the page?

   - You could call a javascript event that resends the new page size.
2. Are you willing to delay the page load?

   - If a user visits your page, they would have to post to your API, and then save the data in the session. You might need some sort of CSRF verification. Then you would have this saved, but you'd need to somehow get the data back to the client. You could return it in the response of the post request, refresh the page, etc.

If I needed to do this, I would load the images with javascript after requesting them from the API with an AJAX request. I would just fill the page with `innerHTML=` the `response.data` or something like that.

#### Another Idea Entirely

If this is about image size... You could update the image href to request the image at a particular size, forgoing the session and CSRF tokens, and simply making a dynamic image request.

For example:

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;charset=UTF-8");

var image_suffix = '_' width + 'px_' + width + 'px.png'; // some_image_1200px_800px.png
```

Comment: The dynamic image tag loading is the best solution if OP insists that it's impossible to do this any other way. However, I don't think a CSRF token is necessary when the server is only serving images.

Comment: thank you for this answer. do you have better idea for load image without excess size? i know i can hold images every size on my server. but there is 15-20 sizes i need to load images and i need to to this based on user's browser width. i dont want to hold images with every size on my server.

Comment: @Cihan If you need to load exact image dimensions on your server, but you don't want to store all of those images, you can edit the image dimensions in your code when its requested. However, this would be a lot to ask of a server on a single response.

Comment: @101arrowz Yeah, I don't know if CSRF tokens are necessary either, but he mentioned session storage so I thought I'd bring it up. I would recommend it if users also had personal information in the session or had been authenticated at some point.

Comment: @Cihan This is more of an anecdote, but if you're resizing images on your server, it would save you a lot of performance if you cached them. Lots of us are using computers with the same dimensions. No need to calculate that twice.

Comment: Why not just vectorize the image using some sort of autotracer? Small file sizes, none of this dynamic image sizing...If you absolutely need, you can have, say, 30 image sizes, then find the lowest resolution image above both the height and width of the browser window with some JavaScript logic, then load the image with a dynamic tag.

Comment: @101arrowz "Why not just vectorize the image using some sort of autotracer" can you explain this more? my english not good

Comment: [Here's an online autotracer](https://www.autotracer.org/). There are tools like [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) if you know how to use the command line. They convert PNG, JPG, etc. files into vectors that can be scaled to any resolution with no loss in quality. You might need to tweak some settings to get a good-quality, small output.

Comment: You could also [compress a big image](https://squoosh.app/) at a resolution higher than any browser could ever need to a tiny size, then you would just serve it to all browser resolutions and not care about file size.

Comment: @Cihan I answered your questions because you asked, but if any of 101arrows solutions work, you should do them because they all would be more performant then what I posted.